# What are the common proper ways of inserting variable number of related records into data base table in SQL

Tags: mysql, database

Pardon me if the question is unclear - I have limited DB dev experience. I have two simple tables in mySQL:

*User table*, with two columns: **userId**, **userName**. And an
*Item table*, with two columns: **itemId**, **itemDescription**

I need to implement a feature where a user can flag any item (any number of items) as favorites. I would like to know what are some of the common approaches to doing this. I figured I create a new table with a **userId** and a **itemId** as two columns where each row would describe a single favorite item for a specific user. But that seems inefficient as it would duplicate user id information and also as many different users mark items would be slow to operate on.

If there is some "standard" way of dealing with this, I'll take any search hints!
Thanks!

Comment: how is it inefficient? somehow you've got to record that "user X likes item Y". what you've described **IS** the proper solution - a normalized table design. Just because it takes YOU a long time to look through a list of numbers means nothing. That's what computers are for - digging through long lists of stuff and finding things quickly. that's the whole point of a database.

Comment: I agree with @MarcB. The only thing I would like to add is that you can add indexes on the two columns in the link table (userId and itemId), to speed up the search.

Comment: @MarcB I though perhaps a proper solution would involve introducing an extra column into either of the existing tables - for instance. But if this is the standard way to go, awesome! Thanks!

Comment: one extra column would mean you're storing multiple IDs in a single field, e.g. `1,2,3,9,500,999999`. now you've got the problem of "how do I remove a deleted id?" or "how can I do a group-by on sub-values of a field", blah blah blah.